# Error causing deformation text in jsPDF with use autoTable

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

There is an error that causes the text to stretch out of the first column, causing the text to be below the other columns, see the image:

[image: Captura de tela de 2022-11-23 13-07-59]

**This is the code:**

```
const colStyle = {
   0: { 
        halign: 'left'
    } 
};

doc.autoTable(dataRel.columns, dataRel.rows, {
                        theme: 'grid',
                        margin: { top: y, left: x },
                        startY: y,
                        bodyStyles: { valign: 'top' },
                        columnStyles: colStyle,
                        styles: {
                            cellPadding: 1,
                            overflow: 'linebreak',
                            font: 'helvetica',
                            textColor: [41, 43, 44],
                            rowPageBreak: 'auto',
                            valign: 'middle',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fontSize: '9'
                        },
                        headStyles: {
                            fillColor: [255, 255, 255],
                            textColor: [41, 43, 44],
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            font: 'helvetica',
                            lineWidth: 0.1,
                            lineColor: [236, 238, 239]
                        },
                        alternateRowStyles: { fillColor: [242, 242, 242] },
                        willDrawCell: function (data) {
                            const doc = data.doc;
                            const rows = data.table.body;

                            if (data.row.index === rows.length - 1) {
                                doc.setFontStyle('bold');
                            }
                        }
});
```

**Documentation:**

- [AutoTable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable)
- [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the stretched lines, in my case they were seemingly randomly in one line in a multi-line text in a table cell.
By having the original data in a text file, I was able to figure out that there were only what appeared to be normal spaces in those lines - but actually narrow no-break space characters (U+202F) crept in.
After I had removed these, in my case with

```
text.replace(/[^\S\n]/g, " ")
```

I had no more formatting problems.

Your question is already a bit older and I hope you could solve the problem already. But maybe it helps one or the other who has the same error!